# Can the AMP framework interfere with WordPress security plugins such as WordFence?

Tags: wordpress, security, plugins, amp-html

I'm building a self-hosted WordPress site, using the AMP for WP plugin. Will the AMP framework interfere with the firewall functions of WordFence or similar security plugins? 
Thank you!

Answer (score 0):

You would need to download and test both plugins to be sure. The plugin publisher may be able to answer, but I would test them to be sure.